# truncate string, should be shorter when more capitals are used

Tags: php, truncate

```
<echo $this->Text->truncate(strip_tags($news['Newspost']['article_' . $lang]), 200, array('ending' => ' ...', 'exact' => false, 'html' => true));>
```

We're currently using this on our website to create a preview of newsposts on our main page.
When the newsposts contains too many CAPITALS or symbols with a bigger width (@# ...) the truncate does not work correctly and an extra line is shown.

One solution would be to just shorten the truncate enough, but that wouldn't look very good for normal posts.

What would be the best way to go about this?
There's about 10-20 of these posts on a page and when important we have a lot of simultaneous users (100-500) on our website.
So I don't want to add something weird that'll slow down the site by too much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php



    function count_capitals($s) {
        return strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $s));
    }

    function truncate_str($str, $limit=30) {
        if( $limit < 3 ) $limit = 3;
        if( strlen($str) > $limit ) return substr($str, 0, $limit - 3) . ' ...';
        return $str;
    }   

    function showTextByCapitalPercent($percent,$str) {
        $int_percent = (int)$percent;
        // 0-24% capitals
        if( in_array($int_percent,range(0,24) ) ) {
            return truncate_str($str, $limit=50)."\n";
        }

        // 25-49% capitals
        if( in_array($int_percent,range(25,49) ) ) {
            return truncate_str($str, $limit=40)."\n";
        }   

        // 50-74% capitals
        if( in_array($int_percent,range(50,74) ) ) {
            return truncate_str($str, $limit=30)."\n";
        }    

        // 75-100% capitals
        if( in_array($int_percent,range(75,100) ) ) {
            return truncate_str($str, $limit=20)."\n";
        }
        return '';
    }   


    $str1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ";
    $str2 = "Fusce eu mauris libero. Morbi auctor lobortis ex, pulvinar fermentum massa. ";
    $str3 = "Cras DOLOR IPSUM, CONGUE EU ornare VITAE, egestas SED URNA. ";
    $str4 = "Nunc NEC urna MOLLIS, rutrum nisi eu, bibendum turpis.";


    $percent_capitals_str1 = (count_capitals($str1)*100)/strlen($str1);
    $percent_capitals_str2 = (count_capitals($str2)*100)/strlen($str2);
    $percent_capitals_str3 = (count_capitals($str3)*100)/strlen($str3);
    $percent_capitals_str4 = (count_capitals($str4)*100)/strlen($str4);


    echo "<pre>";

    echo "capitals str1: ".$percent_capitals_str1."%\n";
    echo "capitals str2: ".$percent_capitals_str2."%\n";
    echo "capitals str3: ".$percent_capitals_str3."%\n";
    echo "capitals str4: ".$percent_capitals_str4."%\n";

    echo "\n-------------------------\n";

    echo "str1: ".showTextByCapitalPercent($percent_capitals_str1,$str1)."\n";
    echo "str2: ".showTextByCapitalPercent($percent_capitals_str2,$str2)."\n";
    echo "str3: ".showTextByCapitalPercent($percent_capitals_str3,$str3)."\n";
    echo "str4: ".showTextByCapitalPercent($percent_capitals_str4,$str4)."\n";



/*
out
capitals str1: 3.5087719298246%
capitals str2: 2.6315789473684%
capitals str3: 51.666666666667%
capitals str4: 18.518518518519%

-------------------------
str1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetur adipisc ...
str2: Fusce eu mauris libero. Morbi auctor lobortis e ...
str3: Cras DOLOR IPSUM, CONGUE EU ...
str4: Nunc NEC urna MOLLIS, rutrum nisi eu, bibendum  ...
*/

?>
```

get capital percent from your string and apply a truncate by the size of percent

ex1: capitals=10% show only 50 chars

ex2: capitals=21% show only 33 chars ....